# Shiv'a Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yaakov Avinu lived for 147 years

Answer (score 6):

There are 147 chapters in the Book of Tehillim.

(According to a book of Aggadata quoted in the Yerushalmi (Shabbos 16:1), and from there in Tosafos to Pesachim 117a, and in Baal Haturim to Gen. 47:28.)

A great deal of ink has been spilled on how to reconcile this with the 150 chapters that we have. From various references in the Gemara, as well as present-day Yemenite practice, it seems that some single chapters that we have were originally split in two, and conversely, some that we have as two chapters were originally one.

Comment: Just like how Bamidbar is thought to contain 2 extra books making grand total actually 7 books of the Torah vs. 5 as we know. Interesting. Water drawers and wood choppers

Answer (score 3):

There are 147 unique body parts in the human body.

The *mishna* in [Ahalos 1:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%97) lists that 101 have symmetrical counterparts and 46 are central.

Some are bones. Others are not, but all are referred to by the single term "*evarim*".