# Chamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

150 perakim in Tehillim

Comment: maybe... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4684/759

Answer (score 4):

150 years after the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdash (in the year 530 Seleucid Era = 3979 since Creation), Rav left Eretz Yisrael and returned to his native Babylonia, marking a new era in the study and dissemination of Torah there. (Iggeres R' Sherira Gaon)

According to R' Yehudah Halevi (Kuzari 3:67), this is also the year in which R' Yehudah Hanassi (Rabbeinu Hakadosh) completed the composition of the Mishnah.

Answer (score 4):

Parashas Noach 7:24-

וַיִּגְבְּרוּ הַמַּיִם עַל-הָאָרֶץ חֲמִשִּׁים וּמְאַת יוֹם

Answer (score 4):

Ways that the student was able to prove that a sheretz is tahor ([eiruvin 13b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=461&size=1))

Comment: shtayim, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this interesting entry in the Mi  Yodeya series! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

"ויבן עזיהו מגדלים...‏"

(Now I have the tune stuck in my head!)

Josephus, *Antiquities*, book 9, chapter 10, says he built 150-cubit-tall towers.

Comment: What tune, and who built?

Comment: @R'IM: Uziyahu built, and the tune to "vayiven uziyahu". Not sure how to transcribe it here (if for no other reason than because I don't know musical notation).

Comment: Oh, silly me. I read that three times as "eizehu."

Answer (score 1):

The Teiva was 300 Cubits (Amos) long **which = 150 yds**

Comment: Huh? שלש מאות אמה ארך התבה (Gen. 6:15).

Comment: Gershon was probably thinking of the Mabul which strengthened for  150 days

Comment: Sorry - did it on the fly and left out critical info - see correction above

Answer (score 0):

Shimshon sent 150 pairs of foxes to the field of philistines Shoftim Perek 15