# Why do we specifically skip Lo Lanu and Ahavti?

Tags: passover, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, rosh-chodesh-new-month, hallel

On those days on which we skip part of Hallel (i.e. Rosh Chodesh and the last six days of Pesach), why were the first pieces of Tehillim 115 and 116 (Lo Lanu and Ahavti) the pieces chosen to be skipped?

Comment: Different customs exist[ed] for which parts to skip http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3a03.htm#8 https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=213

Comment: Calling lo lanu "the first part of 115" is a little misleading.  I would call it "the middle part of 114-115" which is the actual unit.

Comment: @Heshy I’m using the common convention of the Christian chapter breaks. I’m aware that the actual parsha breaks vary by tradition, but if I phrase it this way I think people will understand what I’m talking about better.

Comment: And both times we skip 11 verses!

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102129/759

Answer (score 3):

[Elyah Rabbah 422:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41130&st=&pgnum=272) quotes from [Binyamin Ze'ev 361](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=620&st=&pgnum=357) who suggests that we skip these pieces specifically because the paragraphs of Lo Lanu and Hashem Zecharanu contain the same themes for the most part, and the paragraphs of Ahavti and Mah Ashiv contain some of the same themes.

Comment: I find it counterintuitive that we’d skip these paragraphs because their themes are repeated elsewhere yet repeat the end of 118 specifically because those themes are *not* repeated.